# Can a thread in ASP.NET work keep continue after Response.End?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, iis, httpapplication

I want to make a tcp connection to a device and keep continously retrieve data from device. I want to start this with a simple request and keep it working background even Page response completed. Is this possible in asp.net?

Comment: You will need to spawn a new thread and do the device communication on that thread. You cannot use the request-handling thread because the host (IIS, etc) will return it to the request thread-pool after completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a thread in ASP.NET work keep continue after Response.End?

Yes, you can if you do not care or do not need the result.

*For example, in the following code, you call AddLogAsync and insert a log, but you not care whether insert successful or not.*

```
public Task AddLogAsync(Log log)
{
   return Task.Run(() => AddLog(log));
}

private void AddLog(TraceLog traceLog)
{
   // Do something here.
}
```

> I want to make a tcp connection to a device and keep continously
>   retrieve data from device. I want to start this with a simple request
>   and keep it working. Is this possible in asp.net?

I'm not really understanding above question. After Response.End, you cannot return anything, although you can continue work on something in different thread.

Comment: Win, is it possible to keep alive an object which is using to connect to devices and retrieve data from them even page response.ended? And how would you be sure if this object is alive and doing its job when device fire events(attendance control devices)?

Comment: My answer is you cannot sure whether the process is alive. If you want to be sure, you need to schedule a task such as [hangfire](http://hangfire.io/). Basically, after Response.End, the connection between a device and server is disconnected. In other words, server cannot talk to device anymore. If you want server talks to device, you want to use different technology called  [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr). Hangfire and SignalR are out of the scope of original question.